# A question in numerical range of matrix polynomyal

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$$ a matrix polynomial(${A_j} \in {C^{n \times n}},j = 0,1,2....m$), and $$A = \left\{ {\lambda  \in C:{v^*}P(\lambda )v = 0,v \in C,{v^*}v = 1} \right\}$$
Why is $A$ always closed?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$.

EDIT. I am not awake.

Let $(\lambda_p)_p$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to $\lambda_0$.

Since the function $\lambda\rightarrow P(\lambda)$ is continuous, $v^*P(\lambda_p)v=0$ converges to $v^*P(\lambda_0)v$ and we are done.